# How to disable an html button in a .twig page

Tags: jquery, html

i want to disable an HTML button at the documemt.ready() of the twig page, in a Xibo CMS.

This is my code:

```
{% block formTitle %}
    {% trans "Edit page" %}
{% endblock %}

{% block formButtons %}
    {% trans "Cancel" %}, XiboDialogClose()
    {% trans "Save" %}, $("#layoutEditForm").submit()
{% endblock %}

{% block formHtml %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li class="active"><a href="#general" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span>{% trans "General" %}</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <form id="layoutEditForm" class="form-horizontal" method="put" action="{{ urlFor("titanBoard.edit", {id: layout.layoutId}) }}">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="general">

                        My test form

                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="background">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2">
                            <img id="bg_image_image" data-url="{{ urlFor("library.download") }}?preview=1&width=100&height=56" data-not-found-url="{{ theme.uri("img/forms/filenotfound.gif") }}" alt="{% trans "Background thumbnail" %}" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $('document').ready(function () {
            $('.save-button').prop('disabled', true);
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

.save-button is the class of the save button, but when the form is shown the save button is already enabled. How can i disable it?

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about .twig, but you could hack it with css by adding `pointer-events:none`, then `pointer-events:auto` when you want the button to be clickable again.  This will not work in IE9 and lower without a shim.